# Lua Roblox How to set spicific players health to 0

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a game in Roblox that spawns every player onto a map and they have to try battle each other. However my problem is when the last player is left I don't know how to spawn him back in my lobby. I have all the players in the game stored in an array, once a person dies they are removed from the array. I have tried setting the last players health to 0 but whatever way the player is stored in the array it won't work with getting their humanoid.

This is my code so far:

```
if #plrs == 1 then
    plrs[1].Character.Humanoid.Health = 0
end
```

I am making my plrs array like this:

```
local plrs = {}

for i, player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
    if player then
        table.insert(plrs,player) --Add each player to the Player array
    end
end
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you include how you make your `plrs` array?

Comment: I updated it to show how I make the array, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everybody who tried to help.

I figured out my own problem after a lot of research and reading back through my code.

```
if #plrs == 1 then
    player.Character.Humanoid.Health = 0
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [`player:LoadCharacter()`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Player/LoadCharacter) to force spawn a new player character. This method has the advantage of not showing a death screen, instead it destroys the old character and spawns a new one straight after.

You should note that this method will also clear their backpack and playerGui just incase any of that is important to your game.

---

As a side note, there is no need to use a for loop to get the players as the function [`game.Players:GetPlayers()`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Players/GetPlayers) returns an array as it is already. Unless you are doing additional checks to the players in that loop all you need is this:

```lua
local plrs = game.Players:GetPlayers()
```

Answer (score -3):

You have a standard indexing error here. In code, you always start counting at 0, and you are actually asking for the `(plrs[1])` **second** item in your array. Simply change your code to this:

```
if #plrs == 1 then
    plrs[0].Character.Humanoid.Health = 0
end
```

Comment: "it is customary in Lua to start arrays with index 1. The Lua libraries adhere to this convention; so, if your arrays also start with 1, you will be able to use their functions directly." - https://www.lua.org/pil/11.1.html

Comment: this isn't it because i have other code using plrs[1] that works

Comment: No thats definitely not it because lua starts its arrays at 0 unlike most languages.